# getting all values instead of getting the search results

Tags: php, codeigniter, datepicker

Here i want to get the result based on the dates that i would like to give but returning back the entire results 
the databse looks like this

```
customer_account_id     customer_id     date           code     
    11                    55         01-01-2017     ALI HAJI        
    12                    55         02-01-2017     ALI HAJI                
    13                    55         03-01-2017     ALI HAJI                
    125                   65         01-02-2017     SHARFU              
    126                   55         02-02-2017     ALI HAJI        
    127                   55         03-02-2017     ALI HAJI            
    128                   55         31-01-2017     ALI HAJI
```

controller looks like this

```
public function report()
{
    $from=$this->input->post('from_date');
    $to = $this->input->post('to_date');
    $from1= date('d-m-Y', strtotime($from));
    $to1= date('d-m-Y', strtotime($to));
    $data['result']= $this->Account_model->get_report($from1,$to1)->result();
    $this->load->view('report_payment_details',$data);

}
```

my model looks like this

```
public function get_report($from1,$to1)
{

    $this->db->order_by('customer_account_id','desc');
    $this->db->where('date >=', $from1);
    $this->db->where('date <=', $to1);

    return $this->db->get('customer_accounts');
   }
```

Here if i choose the dates between `01-01-2017` and `03-01-2017` then also the entire results will be displayed.The problem is only the first two values is considering from the date for example if i consider 01-01-2017 here only 01 is considering and remaining not.please help me to solve this

Comment: try to print the query using `$this->db->last_query()`

Comment: the entire result is fetching

Comment: have you printed the query ? execute the printed query on your mysql console

Comment: any body have any idea, the problem is only the first two values is considering from the date for example if i consider `01-01-2017` here only 01 is considering and remaining not.

Comment: check the value for $from1 and $to1 it should be in the form of yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: its in the format of dd-mm-yyyy.i want the result to be in this format

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141496/discussion-between-nishant-nair-and-user-777).

Comment: i think nobody is knowing this answer

Answer (score 0):

Firstly the `datatype` of the column should be `date`. Try below code.

```
$this->db->order_by('customer_account_id','desc');
$this->db->where('date >=', $from1);
$this->db->where('date <=', $to1);
$result = $this->db->get('customer_accounts');
echo $this->db->last_query();
print_r($result);
```

Comment: if you are getting the result so it should print the query which is getting executed

Comment: SELECT * FROM `customer` WHERE `category_id` = 2 am getting like this

Comment: How can it be ? you are executing query for `customer_accounts`  and `customer` table is getting used

Comment: thats what am confused i will paste my code that i used please see

Answer (score 0):

try this one sir

```
    $this->db->order_by('customer_account_id DESC');
    $this->db->limit('1');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function get_report($from1,$to1)
{

    $this->db->order_by('customer_account_id','desc');
    $this->db->where('date >=', $from1);
    $this->db->where('date <=', $to1);       
    $this->db->get('customer_accounts');
    echo $this->db->last_query();     // dont return it now just check      
}
```

Comment: know what is the result?